# Getting results where no association between database tables are found using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to find the applications that has no documents and I want to do it using hibernate criteria. Once I use `createAlias` in criteria, I only find the tables with associations. Does anyone have idea how can I do so or is it even possible?

Application.java

```
private int appId;

private String lname;

private String fname;

//getters setter generated
```

Document.java

```
private int appId;

private int docId;
//getters setters generated
```

Here is what my criteria looks like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class, "application");
 criteria.createAlias("application.appId","document");

 if (looking for no association)
 {
 criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("document.appId"));
 }
```

Basically with the way I am setting criteria, I am creating inner join so the restriction condition is not working.

Comment: You said you tried with createAlias, why don't you post the code of that?

Comment: We need more information than that.  Generally, we ask for a [mcve].  Obviously missing from what you've presented are the persistence annotations and the code for your failed attempt.  Probably some example data and corresponding actual and desired results will be helpful, too.

Comment: Posted code for the criteria.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Specifying join type helped me resolve the issue

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class);
    criteria.createAlias("document",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
    if (looking for no association) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("document.appId"));
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong about it? With left join I get results where documents are null and with restrictions I can see the applications that have no documents. If i don't specify join, I do not get application without document in the first place and setting restriction won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Application.class);
criteria.createAlias("document");
if (looking for no association) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("document.appId"));
}
```

Firstly you create a criteria based on Application class. Secondly you assign the alias you want to and finally you apply the desired restriction.

Comment: When we use createAlias , seems like we are creating inner join. So no null appId is displayed in the result and adding restriction does not help. Looks like I have to create a left join.

Comment: You are getting confused. The join that is referred in the documentation has nothing to do with SQL Join. This process just joins the alias name with a particular class.

Comment: when we use createAlias we are " Joining an association using the specified join-type, assigning an alias to the joined association." is this join type inner ?

Comment: I was able to achieve desired result specifying join condition. Appreciate your input.